# WCF Hosting and SQL Server database

Tags: wcf, hosting

Is there anywhere I can host my WCF service and SQL Server database for free?

Comment: You may find it difficult to find one for free especially with IIS/WCF and .Net. Look around for a "Pay As You Go" with ASP.Net where you pay for "what you use".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft is offering introductory, limited accounts for Windows Azure and SQL Azure - to a certain point in terms of size of your database and traffic you generate, it's free.

[Windows Azure / SQL Azure info](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure)

[Windows Azure / SQL Azure pricing info](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/pricing/)

[Windows Azure Special Introductory Offer](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/offers/popup.aspx?lang=en&locale=en-US&offer=MS-AZR-0001P)

> Included each month at no charge:
>
> ```
> * Windows Azure
>       o 25 hours of a small compute instance
>       o 500 MB of storage
>       o 10,000 storage transactions
> * SQL Azure
>       o 1GB Web Edition database (available for first 3 months only)
> * AppFabric
>       o 100,000 Access Control transactions
>       o 2 Service Bus connections
> * Data Transfers (per region)
>       o 500 MB in
>       o 500 MB out
> ```
>
> Any monthly usage in excess of the
>   above amounts will be charged at the
>   standard rates. This introductory
>   special will end on July 31, 2010 and
>   all usage will then be charged at the
>   standard rates.

Completely free SQL Server hosting is very hard to come by - you might find certain hosters that will use SQL Server Express (limited to 4 GB in size, 10 GB as of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express) which doesn't incur licensing costs.

But ultimately: there ain't no such thing as a free lunch! You want services -> you gotta pay (or run the machine yourself)

Comment: Agreed.  Nothing is free (particularly with hosting and SQL Server) but Azure works out hugely cheaper than their competitors and it's brilliantly implemented into Visual Studio.   What's great is that you just pay for what disc space/CPU you use, rather than paying a set fee per database, or per website that you're hosting.  (I used to use GoDaddy, and Azure is *much* cheaper.)